# Suggestions for statistical analysis of serial data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures

Examinees took the same test several times (1-5 times). The data includes the sub-scale scores (interval scale), and an overall score (ordinal score: low, medium, high).

My hypothesis is that the more times the examinee took the test, his scores are higher (i.e. learning effect).

Any suggestion on how to analyze the data and what statistical procedure to use?